# Selecting rows based on values in other table

Tags: r

Probably a beginner-question. I can't select a row based on criteria from other table. Should be simple, but I'm missing something.

I have two tables:

**T1**

```
X    C  
3    a  
4    a  
41   b
```

and

**T2**

```
A    B    C    D  
1    5    a   22  
7   11    a   27  
35  49    b   29
```

I want to add the column D to T1, where X is between A and B in T2, and C=C. So the resulting table should look like this:

**T1b**

```
X    C    D  
3    a    22  
4    a    22  
41   b    29
```

Thanks.

/Chris

Comment: In the future, please try to provide your data as in my answer, so people can copy and paste into an R console.

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution.

Import the data:

```
> con <- textConnection("X C
+ 3 a
+ 4 a
+ 41 b")
> T1 <- read.table(con, sep=" ", header=TRUE)
> close(con)

> con <- textConnection("A B C D
+ 1 5 a 22
+ 7 11 a 27
+ 35 49 b 29")
> T2 <- read.table(con, sep=" ", header=TRUE)
> close(con)
```

Now merge and subset:

```
> T3 <- merge(T1, T2)
> T3[T3$X > T3$A & T3$X < T3$B, c("X", "C", "D")]
   X C  D
1  3 a 22
3  4 a 22
5 41 b 29
```

Comment: for copy-and-pastability as described above, maybe remove the `>` and `+`?